# appending a text to a line in perl

Tags: perl

I have these lines in a file

```
VSSC!.extra181 + NET VSSC!

+ DIRECTION INOUT
+ USE GROUND
+ LAYER BA ( 0 0 ) ( 1500 80870 )
+ PLACED ( 1151560 1571000 ) N ;
```

I need to copy the third line to the end of first line. There are 30,000 similar cases so I just need to know how to do it for one so that I can repeat for thje others.

```
`open (FILE, $filetoget) or die $!
while (<FILE>)
{if($_=~m/regular expression to catch the third line/)
{@array=$_; $line=~s/\!$/ .@array/; print $Line; } `enter code here`
```

i am not getting the appended part..

Comment: Are you planning to modify the files, or just print the content of the files?

Comment: Dummy "please write the regex for me" code is not really an MCVE.

Comment: @hakon haegland... i am trying to just append every 3rd line to first line... i have 30000 similar cases....

Answer (score 1):

This is done very simply using the [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File) module

Just tie an array to the file and append the third array element to the first

It looks like this. The program expects the name of the file to be modified as a parameter on the command line

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

tie my @file, 'Tie::File', $ARGV[0] or die $!;

$file[0] .= $file[2];
```

#### output

```
VSSC!.extra181 + NET VSSC!+ DIRECTION INOUT

+ DIRECTION INOUT
+ USE GROUND
+ LAYER BA ( 0 0 ) ( 1500 80870 )
+ PLACED ( 1151560 1571000 ) N ;
```

Comment: Thank u borodin..... but i have another issue....how can i generalize it?? i have many such lines.... i am getting error if i am using for loop.....